# How to run a Prisma migration with Mysql on Docker with Github-actions

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, github-actions

My application uses Docker to run a MySQL DB, and Prisma to connect to it. I am writing a gh-action which tests the app after each push. I have followed this guide [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-containerized-services/creating-postgresql-service-containers) on how to run docker on gh-actions. I am also testing this action with [act](https://github.com/nektos/act).

My **.github/workflows/main.yml** looks like this:

```
name: NestJS CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - feature/gh-actions

jobs:
  runner-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    container: node:latest

    services:
      mysql:
        image: mysql
        ports:
          - '3306:3306'
        env:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
          MYSQL_DATABASE: db
        options: >-
          --health-interval 10s
          --health-timeout 5s
          --health-retries 5

    steps:
      - name: Check out repository code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm ci

      - name: Apply migrations
        run: npx prisma migrate dev
        env:
          DATABASE_URL: mysql://root:password@mysql:3306/db

      - name: Apply seed
        run: npx prisma db seed

      - name: Test the project
        run: npm run test
```

but I keep getting:

```
| Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at `mysql`:`3306`
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone stuck on the same thing. In order for act to recognize the connection you should use `localhost` instead of `mysql`. Meanwhile that won't work when you actually use it on github, you have to use `mysql` for that case. Really frustrating since you have to change something in order to test it locally which makes no sense in tbe development process. Maybe im missing something from act

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong but I think you should have

`DATABASE_URL: mysql://root:password@localhost:3306/db`?